# How to fix positioning of windows which keep moving?

Tags: visual-studio

Using the debugger in Visual Studio, the "**Breakpoints**" window automatically appears at the bottom of the screen:

[image: window appears]

So I drag and move the window to be alongside of the other windows, such as "**Immediate Window**" and "**Locals**":

[image: window move]

But then when I re-run, for example, unit tests and re-trigger a breakpoint, the window re-opens *again* at the bottom of the screen!

How can I configure Visual Studio to lock the "Breakpoints" window in the position that I want it?